# String to char * conversion for special character

Tags: c++, qt, char, qstring

I have wrote a simple function in C++/Qt to transform QString to char*.

The function is working fine but I had some issues on some specific character. for example "piña colada" as the QString Parameter is transformed to "pi?a colada". something wrong I think in the toLatin1 conversion.

I want "piña colada" from QString to stay "piña colada" in char *

```
char *convertQStr2char(QString str) {
    QByteArray latin_str;
    char *return_str;
    latin_str = str.toLatin1();
    return_str = latin_str.data();
    return return_str;
}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: The object latin_str is destroyed on function exit, so return_str will point to invalid memory outside the function. You'll need to allocate it dynamically, and take care of its proper release.

Comment: This link may help you, please visit  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714278/c-string-encoding-utf8-without-libiconv

Answer (score 1):

Either latin1 cannot represent the ñ character or when you actually print the character it's in the wrong encoding. What you can try is to use `toLocal8Bit` instead of `toLatin1`, that will ensure the character encoding used is the one set on the machine. But better would be to encode using UTF8, so `toUtf8`, that will preserve any kind of special characters.

And as pointed out in the other answer, apart from the encoding issues, your current code will result in invalid read, too.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. As commented, return type was changed for better memory management:

```
std::string convertQStr2char(QString str) {
    return std::string( str.toLatin1().constData() );
}

// usage:
std::string temp = convertQStr2char( str );
const char* tempChar = temp.c_str();
```

Comment: Thanls jpo38, related to the comment of Janick, do you think we need to change toLatin1 to toUtf8 ?

Comment: I would say try both and pickup the one that works....and if they both work choose toLocal8Bit ;-)

Comment: issue : error: cannot initialize return object of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'const char *'
    return std::string( str.toLatin1().constData() ).c_str();
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Sorry. Just make your function return a const char* or cast it using return `const_cast<char*>(  std::string( str.toLatin1().constData() ).c_str() );`

Comment: The temporary string immediately goes out of scope and is destroyed when the function exits leaving a dangling pointer and the same problem the OP already has.

Comment: So I will change my post to return std::string. This is safer.